# Unable to map the route post login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am a beginner ROR programmer, trying to build an application in which a new user can signup. Once the user sign up is successful, user can login with the signed up email and password.

When I hit the login button after filling the login form, it shows me the error:

> No routes matching "Post".

sessions_controller.rb:

[image: sessions_controller]

users_controller.rb:

[image: users_controller]

routes.rb:

```
root 'users#index'
get "/app/views/users/signup.html.erb", to: "usesrs#new", as:"signup"
post '/users', to: 'users#create'
get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'

resources :users do
  resources :sessions
end
```

index.html.erb(login page):

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">Dropbox</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">Log in</h2>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for :user do |f| %>
      <label>Email</label>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
    <label>Password</label>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox, col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %>
  </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
    <a href="/app/views/users/signup.html.erb">Sign up</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone guide me with what is wrong with my code and how can I correct it.

Comment: Could you add the view file for the log in form please?

Comment: I have added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

In `form_for` you are passing `:user`, so rails will set the  attribute `action` in your `form` to a `User` route, but you want to send the data to `session#create`, so you must specify the correct `url` (i.e. `"/login"`), like this:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: "/login" do |f| %>
```

You can read more about `form_for` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).